# Quiero conectar mi base de datos mysql a php pero al momento de correr mi codigo me marca Parse error: syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Cuando quiero correr mi codigo me aparece:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''tabla3''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Mi código es este, no puedo encontrar que puede ser el error

```
<?php
  include 'include/conexion.php';
  $conexion=conecta();
  ejecuta($conexion, "ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='dd/mm/yyyy'");
  $sql = “select * from 'tabla3';”;
  $res=ejecuta($conn, $rsql);

  while(($fila=oci_fetch_array($res)) != false){
    echo "<td align='center'>".$fila['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$fila['Centro_trab']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$fila['Folio_post']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$fila['Estatus_post']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$fila['Nombre']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$fila['Telefono']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$fila['Telefono2']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$fila['CURP']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$fila['Correo_e']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$fila['Fecha_ini']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$fila['Nombre_tutor']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$fila['Plan_trabajo']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$fila['Palabras_clave']."</td>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Parece ser que el error esta en su query. Comparta su consulta sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error esta en:

```
$sql = "select * from 'tabla3';";
```

No deberias utilizar `'tabla3'` sino simplemente `tabla3` de la siguiente forma:

```
$sql = "select * from tabla3;";
```

O bien utilizar comilla pero en este caso de esta forma:

```
$sql = "select * from `tabla3`;";
```

Para obtener este tipo de comilla o también denominado **(acento grave)** puedes utilizar el código ascii `96`

Espero te funcione ;) Saludos